# How do I add content from a view in Drupal with arguments?

Tags: drupal, view

I have a Drupal view that displays vacation leaves for a particular employee.

I want to have a button or link right on this view that says 'Add Vacation Leave'.  When this button/link is clicked, I want the create content form for Vacation Leave to be displayed with the employee's name already filled in.

When 'Save' is clicked, I would like to go right back to the view, with my new content added.  Is all of this possible?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without much trouble.

To add the link, you could make a custom template for the view where you add the link. It will be the same for all users, something like, `node/node_type/add`. You should make the link with the `l()` function, and remember to add the destination to where they should be redirected back to. You should get a url like this: `/node/node_type/add&destination=/url/to/current/page` (the / being escaped ofcause).

With destination being set, the default node form, should take care of everything and redirect the user back to the url he came from.

Comment: Thanks googletorp - this works great!  Now I just have to figure out the passing arguments and filling in the form thing...

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If I am reading this right, you can write a simple module that implements hook_form_alter, then prefill the form field by doing:

```
global $user;
$form['name_of_form_field']['#value'] = $user->name;
```

You can also adjust the redirect within the same function.

There is also a module that can auto populate based on URL variables.

http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

Comment: I tried Prepopulate, but it didn't work at all for me - I provide the syntax just like the documentation says, but nothing is changed on my form.  Perhaps I need to take this up with the module's authors.